# Save any View at run time on Android permanetly

Tags: android-view

I am seeing the application Pulse and  want to make an application like its some features. One of them is to add a new View at run time by user choice and save it . I am confused that how they did it , I mean how a View could be save at run time. Was it by SharedPreferences  or other way? 
If it is please help me with a piece of code of View . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yes you can do this. for this if you are creating an object on any event suppose
```

you are creating four buttons after clicking on button so it can be done at run time and

these objects can be saved at  run time in sharedpreference object. so when you will open

next time your activity will save the objects that were in sharedprefernce object. so by

this way you can do this